# Сортировка объекта по ключам с массива

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Нужна помощь в сортировке.
Мне приходит объект. в нем данные моих карточек услуг.
У меня есть форма . С формы приходит массив с выбором услуг которые проставил пользователь.
Услуг может быть несколько. Мне нужно проверить каждую карточку на вхождение всех полей которые пришли с массива. С точным совпадением.
Может есть пример.
Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Вам стоит включить в вопрос примеры структур данных. И уточнить, что вы понимаете под сортировкой объекта. Имеется в виду массив объектов? Как его нужно отсортировать — вынести в начало объекты с совпадающими ключами? Отсортировать по степени совпадения ключей? Пока вопрос неясен.

Comment: Добрый день. Да у меня массив объектов . Приходит с json. У  меня там услуги разные. [{"name": "газель", "carryingCapacity": "2 тонны"  },{"name": "газель удлиненная ", "carryingCapacity": "3 тонны"  }]. И еще в обкатках будут хранится доп услуги. А массив получает с формы доп услуги ['грузчики', 'поднять на этаж']. Нужно отсортировать карточки услуг так чтоб вывелись только те которые имеют данные свойства

Comment: const out = [];
      (Object.values(data).map(e =>{
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if(Object.values(e).includes(result[i])){
        out[out.length] = e;
      }
      console.log('result', out );
    }
    }));

Comment: Если массив с формы содержит только дополнительные услуги, стоит также показать, как они хранятся в массиве карточек: каждая доп. услуга как отдельный ключ или как элемент массива с общим ключом.

Comment: Вы можете написать по нормальному, какие данные у вас на входе, и что должно быть на выходе?

Comment: На данный момент у меня сортирует так. Но выводит карточки услуг те которые есть хоть одно совпадение. А мне нужно точное совпадение.

Comment: [{"name": "газель", "carryingCapacity": "2 тонны","mover": "да", "
raiseToFloor"; "да"  },{"name": "газель удлиненная ", "carryingCapacity": "3 тонны" }].

Comment: Все доп услуги хранятся в массиве объектов. В каждой услуги они могут быть разные но и есть одинаковые.

Comment: на выходе должен быть массив обетов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно что вам нужно, но если что могу дополнить код

```js
const arr = [1,2,3]

const arr2 = [
  {
    id: 5
  },
  {
    id: 2
  }
]

const arr3 = arr2.filter(item => {
  return arr.includes(item.id)
})

console.log(arr3)
```

Comment: В этом примере что вы скинули только одна проверка по id. А мне нужно пройтись по всему массиву объектов и отобрать только те объекты в которых есть параметры с массива

Comment: Вам нужна проверка по нескольким полям?

Comment: Да! На точное совпадение по нескольким полям